# Vcs для больших файлов

Tags: git, контроль-версий

Какие есть инструменты для контроля версий больших файлов?
Пробовал к примеру Git lfs, но я так понимаю он не фиксирует изменения файлов, сменил dll файл, а он его не учел и оставил старый.

Comment: А, это файл добавлен в репозиторий?

Comment: *"сменил dll файл, а он его не учел и оставил старый"* Значит что-то неправильно сделали.

Comment: Не ответ на ваш вопрос, но советую посмотреть: [Git Large File Storage](https://git-lfs.github.com/)

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov совсем не ответ - он упомянут прямо вопросе :)

Comment: @PashaPash - маленькими буквами и без ссылки - не щитово! (не заметил я)